# I want to add the pytest tag as an additional column to the HTML report, but I have no idea how

Tags: html, pytest, report

I want to add the pytest tag as an additional column to the HTML report, but I have no idea how. Has anyone solved this? Thnx!

import pytest
from Script_1 import Script_1_test_function
from script_2 import script_2_test_function

## Define the test suite

class TestSuite:
@pytest.mark.regression
def test_Script_1(self):

```
    Script_1_test_function()

@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_Script_2(self):
    # Call the test function or method from script_1.py
    Script_2_test_function()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
pytest.main([**file**])

I want to have a marks (Smoke & Regresion) inside a HTML report for each test script.

Comment: Are you using the `pytest-html` plugin?

Comment: Yes. I am using html plugin. It is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [plugin documentation to modify the results table](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#modifying-the-results-table) and implement something like below in a `conftest.py` file:

```py
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.insert(1, html.th("Marker"))
    cells.pop()


def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    cells.insert(1, html.td(report.description))
    cells.pop()


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    markers = [mark.name for mark in item.iter_markers()]
    report.description = str(*markers)
```

So a test like below...

```py
import pytest


@pytest.mark.smoke
def test_report():
    pass
```

... run with `pytest --html=report.html --self-contained-html` would generate a report like this:

[image]